# Ownnership of QState. Do I need to delete all QStates?

Tags: qt, state-machine

I added my state to m. This code will delete mystate?

```
QStateMachine *m = new QStateMachine(); 
QState *mystate = new QState();
m->addState(mystate);
delete m;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the same as with layouts. 
The state machine will take ownership if you add the state  and releases ownership when you manually remove the state from the state machine.

> void QStateMachine::removeState ( QAbstractState * state ) 
>   Removes the given state from this state machine.
>   The state machine releases ownership
>   of the state.